# How to choose "remote login via xdmcp" at the login window in RHEL6/7?

Tags: rhel, xdmcp

In RHEL5, I can press F10 to choose "remote login via xdmcp" at the login window, how to do the same thing in RHEL6/7?

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume your unable to do that now? Assuming that. Ensure that you have the following in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`:

```
[security]
 ...

DisallowTCP=fale
AllowRemoteRoot=true
...
[xdmcp]
Enable=true
```

`DisallowTCP` is `true`, and `AllowRemoteRoot` is `false` as I recall, and `[xdmcp]` `Enable` may, or may not be true. But you'll need to ensure it's there, and `true`.
I only mention `AllowRemoteRoot` in case you need it. Otherwise simply leave it `false`.

EDIT: sorry I inadvertently inverted the entry for `DisallowTCP` (now corrected)

EDIT2: Here's a [complete rundown](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/remote-login-with-gdm-and-vnc-on-centos-7-rhel-7-configure-vnc-on-xinetd-with-xdmcp-centos-7-rhel-7.html) for RedHat/Centos (too much info to post here inline).

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for my unclear representation, my question is how to remote login from a rhel6/7 client to another linux host via xdmcp directly at the login windows.

Comment: I've updated my Answer. I think it should have all the information you need. Please don't forget to upvote if it solves it for you.